# A strange or rare using of the adverb yet?

Tags: adverbs

However, Maya hieroglyphs is really a bible for modern man, its mystery until today, ***yet*** to unlock.

1. Would you please throw a light on whether or not the commas are put properly grammatically?
2. Having taken into account the following, would you tell me if there has been the same usage of the word yet in context? if not, what's that?

   Explanations by Free Dictionary:. 'have yet to'
   Instead of saying that something 'has not yet happened', you can say that it has yet to happen. People often use this structure to show that they do not expect something to happen.

I have yet to meet a man I can trust.

[enter link description here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/yet)

Comment: I think you're mistaken if you're supposing that people use ***yet to be*** to show that they "do not expect something to happen". In fact, it's almost precisely the opposite. If you say something is *yet to happen* (as opposed to *hasn't happened*) the strong implication is you accept/think/know that it ***will happen at some point in the future***.

Comment: Remaining as close to your original thought as possible, I'd rewrite as: "Mayan hieroglyphs are really a bible for modern man, their mystery, as of today, yet to be unlocked."  However I think *secret* might be better than *mystery* as something to be unlocked.

Comment: @Jim - 'is yet' for me; the rest I concur. The OP construction does stumble somewhat.

Comment: Or ***has** yet*...

Comment: What does this mean? If you say something is yet to happen (as opposed to hasn't happened)

Answer (score 2):

The grammatical phrase would be "yet to be unlocked", because "mystery" is the subject. A passive construction is required.

Also, you cannot have "until today" and "yet to be" together.  *Yet to be done* means that it  remains to be done -- in the future.

*hieroglyphs" is a plural.  "is" is singular.

Comment: And, what is the difference between its mystery until today yet to unlock and its mystery until today is/ has yet to unlock???

Comment: Other than that, I have not written them.

Comment: I cannot get this at all: you cannot have "until today" and "yet to be" together. Yet to be done means that it remains to be done -- in the future.